# Unusual usage of "va"

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

**Here's the context:**

I was once chatting with a Mexican amiga on FB and asked her if we could move to Skype instead (I often practice my Spanish with her on Skype calls). She had to say no because she was out for the weekend that moment but said we could do it on Monday.

**Now here's the conversation:**

**Me:** *Mi micrófono ya no está roto...podemos hablar en Skype si quieres!*
**Amiga:** *Ahora estoy en la calle y ando con mi mamá. Pero me da muchísimo gusto que ya tengas micrófono.*
**Me:** *Sólo te informaba amiga. No te preocupes. :)*
**Amiga:** *Pero el lunes platicamos mucho va!*

The last sentence is where I am slightly confused. I get the gist of it but can't seem to wrap my head around the **va** at the end. What does it stand for here? I looked up the dictionary to see if **ir** has any idiomatic usage that fits this context but didn't find any.

Any help?

**P.S.:** When I asked her for an explanation, she said *Es como decir "lo hacemos?"* but that doesn't make much sense to my simple head. Wouldn't the sentence mean the same thing without the **va**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is also used in Spain and, as far as I can tell by your example, the meaning implies some "alright?", "is it ok?".

In Spain it tends to be more used as "come on", e.g.

> —Va, hazme la cena.

But also like this:

> —¿Hacemos tortilla hoy? —Va.

In this example it's more like "ok" or even "ok, if we must".

Hope this helps...

Comment: Is it like an abbreviated form of vale instead of a conjugated form of ir in that case? I never came across this usage anywhere else in reading...is it some kind of colloquialism?

Comment: I don't think it's an abbreviation of "vale", but the verb "ir" used as an interjection (similarly, "¡venga!" as a way to express impatience, for example). And yes, it is colloquial (not vulgar though).

Answer (score 2):

In Mexico I learned that it’s like another word for ‘si/yeah/right/correct’. Depending on the context it’s able to be applied to different situations and doesn’t always have the same exact definition.

“Pero el lunes platicamos mucho va!“.
‘Va’ in that sentence is saying, ‘we spoke a lot huh?’//‘we spoke a lot, right??’.

I was asked about an ice cream order once and I heard, “¿tú quieres el sabor chocolate va?”

“¿Tienes hambre?”.
‘Va’.

“Que ir al cine para ver la película que acaba de salir y comprar palomitas y nachos”.
‘¡Va!’.

“Tu nombre es ____, ¿veda?”
‘Va’.

I’m not saying that this is textbook definition what that word means. I got the chance to live in Mexico for about a year and have always seen it be used like that.